# Change Css class on a Panel thats located inside a Asp:repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Hello and thanks for taking your time to read this.

I'm trying to change the CSS class of a panel thats located inside a Repeater when I select a RadioButton.

```
<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Show Gallery</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Show List</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<div class="RpOutterFrame" runat="server" id="RpOutterFrame">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RP">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <panel class="ShowDiv" runat="server" id="RpInnerFrame">
                <img runat="server" style="width: 80px;" id="ModelImg" class="ModelImg" src='<%# string.Format("~/Content/Img/ModelImg/{0}", Eval("Image")) %>' />
                <br />
                <%# Eval("Model") %>
            </panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

My C#:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected == true)
    {

        RpOutterFrame.Attributes["class"] = "RpOutterFrame";

        Panel panel = (Panel)this.FindControl("RpInnerFrame");
        panel.CssClass = "ShowDiv2";
    }

}
```

As you can see the Panel already has the class **ShowDiv** and then I would like it to change the class to **ShowDiv2** when I select/click the Radiobutton.

Anyone who can help me figuar what I'm doing wrong or fix the code?

Comment: Not a solution, just an observation: Should be `<asp:Panel>` instead of `<panel>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when i try that i get the following error when i run the page. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Repeater`'s purpose is to repeat something. So normally it contains multiple elements. Therefore the `RepeaterItem` is the `NamingContainer` which must contain unqiue ID's and where you can find your controls via `FindControl(ID)`.

So this does not work since `this` is the `Page` which is *not* the `NamingContainer` of the `Panel`:

```
Panel panel = (Panel)this.FindControl("RpInnerFrame");
panel.CssClass = "ShowDiv2";
```

You have to loop all items:

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in RP.Items)
{
    Panel panel = (Panel)item.FindControl("RpInnerFrame");
    panel.CssClass = "ShowDiv2";
}
```

Apart from that you should use the `ASP:Panel` instead of `Panel`.

So change

```
<panel class="ShowDiv" runat="server" id="RpInnerFrame">
    // ...
</panel>
```

to

```
<ASP:Panel CssClass="ShowDiv" runat="server" id="RpInnerFrame">
    // ...
</ASP:Panel>
```